# Python: call a function inside another function

Tags: python, function, call

regardless of what the functions have to return, my code seems to not call the first function properly, as when I try to pass some doctest it raises the error:

```
File "preg3.py", line 27, in mesDivisions
        if nombreDivisions(llista[0],m)>=nombreDivisions(llista[1],m):
    NameError: global name 'nombreDivisions' is not defined
```

here is my code:

```
def nombreDivisons(n,m):
  x=0
def aux(n,m):
  if n<m:
     return x
  else:
     if n%m==0:
        x=x+1
        return aux(n/m,m)
     else:
        return x

def mesDivisions(llista,m):

  if len(llista)==1:
     return llista[0],nombreDivisions(llista[0],m)
  else:
     if nombreDivisions(llista[0],m)>=nombreDivisions(llista[1],m):
        del llista[1]
        return mesDivisions(llista,m)
     else:
        del llista[0]
        return mesDivisions(llista,m)
```

any ideas why?

Comment: `"nombreDivisons" != "nombreDivisions"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your white space. You want at least one and according to pep8 two blank lines between functions.

You failure is a typo though. It should be `nombreDivisions` but you left out the `i` so it is `nombreDivisons`.

Comment: ... thanks!!!!! @Sean-Perry. I'm almost ashamed of myself, before posting it I read it like 10 times to make sure there wasn't a typo error, sorry to bother with this type of questions!!